# Unable to update user in Mongo atlas db

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo atlas and have created Database access user with Atlas Admin and privileges as dbAdminAnyDatabase. I logged in with "mongosh ".  When i tried to create user or update user i get the error as "MongoServerError: not authorized on test to execute command { createUser: "db_test", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "dbfromcons" } ]".

I tried using the command:

atlas dbuser create --username  --scope ClusterName --role dbAdmin@DBname --projectId  --password

I am using the mongo Atlas in AWS cloud.

I have checked all the credentials are correct and provided admin privileges but unable to create or update.

Comment: In MongoDB Atlas you cannot create/modify users by script. You have to manage users with the web-interface.